# How to implement a multiple conversions in pickerView in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview, converters

I am trying to create a conversion app. I have three units to convert: temperature (fahrenheit, pounds and miles to their metric counterparts).

I want to use a picker view, but I am having difficulties connecting the pickerView to the functionality and actually selecting each unit.

I have been able to implement this in a segmented control, but would like a pickerView to be able to add more conversions in the future.

Thanks!

ViewControlle.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface  ViewController (){
NSArray *devices;
}
@end

//CONVERSIONS

// convert pounds to kilograms
double convertLbsToKgs(double poundsValue){
double kilogramsValue;
kilogramsValue = poundsValue / 2.205;
return kilogramsValue;
}

//convert fahrenheit to celcius
double convertFarenheitToCelcius(double farenheitValue){
double celciusValue;
celciusValue = (farenheitValue - 32) * 0.555;
return celciusValue;
}

//convert miles to kilometers
double convertMilesToKilometers(double milesValue){
double kilometersValue;
kilometersValue = milesValue * 1.609;
return kilometersValue;
}

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

devices = @[@"Pounds", @"Fahernheit", @"Miles"];
self.pickerView.dataSource = self;
self.pickerView.delegate = self;
}

// pickerView datascource & delegate methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
return 1;
 }

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
return devices.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
return devices[row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

self.outputTextBox.text = devices[row];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *inputField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *outputTextBox;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;


@end
```

Comment: i have implemented same code i don't have any issue. please describe in brief what happens.

Comment: I am able to show which row is currently enabled, but I would like to carry out functions to calculate fahrenheit to celsius etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in didselect method.

```
if ([devices[row]  isEqualToString: @"Pounds"]) {
           double kgs =[self convertLbsToKgs:[inputField.text doubleValue]];
            outputTextBox.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",kgs];

        }else if ([devices[row]  isEqualToString: @"Fahernheit"]){
            double celcious =[self convertFarenheitToCelcius:[inputField.text doubleValue]];
            outputTextBox.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",celcious];

        }else if ([devices[row]  isEqualToString: @"Miles"]){
            double kms=[self convertMilesToKilometers:[inputField.text doubleValue]];
            outputTextBox.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",kms];
        }
```